# Python3 requests - cut response

Tags: python-3.x, python-requests

How can i cut the output from a response using Python requests?
The output looks like:

```
...\'\n});\nRANDOMDATA\nExt.define...
```

or

```
...\'\n});\nOTHERRANDOMDATA\nExt.define...
```

And i only want to print out the RANDOMDATA.

```
req = "https://example.org/endpoint"
response = requests.get(req, verify=False)

print (response.content)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `re` module `findall()` function for searching all occurrences of a regular expression in a string.
The following code, just search for the string `RANDOMDATA` in the `response` got from `requests.get()` function

```
import re
req = "https://example.org/endpoint"
response = requests.get(req, verify=False)

print (response.content)
ar = re.findall('RANDOMDATA',str(response.content))
if len(ar):
    print(ar[0])
```

This [link](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html) would be helpful to learn about regular expressions

Additionally, if you have a variable `data` containing a string to b searched, and a variable `t` containing a string to search, you can use,

```
import re
arr = re.findall(t,data)
```

To return all the occurrences of `t` in `data` and :

```
arr = data.find(t)
```

To get the index of the first occurrence of `t` in `data`

Comment: RANDOMDATA is really random, it can be anything.

Comment: you can search using a string instead of the 'RANDOMDATA' string I entered

Comment: Sorry, i don't understand this. Can you give me an example to filter between the two \n?

Comment: While this code may resolve the OP's issue, it is best to include an explanation as to how your code addresses the OP's issue. In this way, future visitors can learn from your post, and apply it to their own code. SO is not a coding service, but a resource for knowledge. Also, high quality, complete answers are more likely to be upvoted. These features, along with the requirement that all posts are self-contained, are some of the strengths of SO as a platform, that differentiates it from forums. You can edit to add additional info &/or to supplement your explanations with source documentation.

Comment: Can someone give me an example?